# Salesforce LWC - Pass standard object to Apex Class

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am trying to pass a Case SObject to apex class as parameter, but is not working. I did not see the `System.debug` on the console. Why?

```
//wire the record
  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
  case;

  setCaseStatus({
        objCase: this.case // also tried this.case.data
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('sucess! ');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error received: code' + error.errorCode + ', ' +
        'message ' + error.body.message);

    });

//Apex class method
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static void setCaseStatus(Case objCase){
       System.debug('CaseService.setCaseStatus.case: ' + objCase);

       objCase.status = 'Working';
       update objCase;
    }
```

Another question: Is it possible apex void method in lwc?

Comment: Have you reviewed some of the wire recipes in the [official repo](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes)? There are some examples for what you're trying to do. Also, double check the trailheads on what wire is for, what imperative apex is for, and also check out the lightning data service ui*API adapters for an apex-less way to update your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer there is no recipe example send a standard sObject,  there is a example with a wrap class is a different case

Comment: It may have been in another trailhead repo, but you're looking for `uiRecordApi` and `recordUpdate`.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question as this addresses a problem which is not documented or available in lwc-recipes. I do have an approach here which I would like to add as an answer but cannot add as it's already closed.

Comment: I am voting to leave closed right now for two reasons which are easily fixable. First, *"is not working"* needs to be more specific. What actual behavior is observed? Is the lack of debug log the only problem? My second issue is the one true question in here doesn't make sense to me. What are you trying to ask by *"is it possible apex void method in lwc?"*?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I think the main question here is -- *Case SObject to apex class as parameter, but is not working*. That will lead to get answers for others as why others are not working in this case.

Comment: But the post, as written, does not contain a clear question or explicitly describe the observed behavior. IMO it still needs an **[edit]** for clarity.

Comment: @AdrianLarson it is a studing case where I did not find on the recipes this recipe https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethodWithComplexParams  is good show as wrapper class the documentation say "sObject—standard and custom sObjects are both supported.", but I do not know how to execute. Sorry my lack  english

Comment: I will leave it to @JayantDas to clean this post up a bit, at which point I will likely reopen.

Comment: @MarcilioDevSfdc You are looking for a way to pass `SObject` from LWC to Apex, is that correct? Can you make sure as Adrian mentioned to edit the post to be more specific, so that this post can be reopened. I think I know how you can achieve it.

Comment: @MarcilioDevSfdc I have added a [new question with answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257058/how-do-i-send-a-sobject-record-from-lwc-to-a-custom-apex-method-to-persist-data) assuming you were looking to achieve passing of `SObject` and performing a DML on it in your custom Apex method. Hope it helps.

Comment: @JayantDas is that what I am looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the code below. I'm also a newbie to lwc and there might be a better way to do than this, but this has worked for me.

```
    import { LightningElement,api,track,wire } from 'lwc';
    import setCaseStatus from '@salesforce/apex/CaseController.setCaseStatus';

    export default class StackExSetCase extends LightningElement {
        @api recordId;
        @api objectApiName;
        @track propselectedStatus = '';
        @wire(setCaseStatus, { propselectedStatus: '$selectedStatus' }) cases;
        handleSave(event) {
            const propselectedStatus = event.target.value;
        }
    }

    <template>
        <lightning-card title="Set Case Status" icon-name="standard:case">
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiName} record-id={recordId}>
                        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
                        <lightning-input-field  value={selectedStatus}
                        field-name="Status"
                    ></lightning-input-field>
                    <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                        <lightning-button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" onclick={handleSave}></lightning-button>
                    </div>
                </lightning-record-edit-form>
            </div>
        </lightning-card>
    </template>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="stackExSetCase">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>Case</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: You have passed the status as parameter I need the Standard sObject case, it is just a studying case not a real  business problem