# How do I pass a SObject record from LWC to a custom Apex method to persist data?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Disclaimer: My answer to this question does not deal with a real business use case scenario. The approach mentioned in my answer was found to be working while going through [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256864/salesforce-lwc-pass-standard-object-to-apex-class). The answer can be definitely improved/fine-tuned based on real business use case scenarios.

---

Going through the [LWC documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc) or the [lwc-recipe](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc), there does not seem to be a scenario which discusses how to pass a `SObject` record from LWC to a custom Apex method to **persist** data. All the examples in documentation or lwc-recipe only discusses about fetching data.

The ones available are using the `lightning/ui*APi*` [`createRecord()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_ui_api) or [`updateRecord()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record), but what if I need to pass it to custom Apex methods evaluating more complex logic before DML operations?

So, how do we send a `SObject` record to a custom Apex method for performing DML operations?

Let's say we have the following Use Case Scenarios:

1. Create a new `SObject` record by constructing an instance of the `SObject` and passing values from LWC to a custom Apex method performing insert
2. Update a `SObject` record fetched on LWC using `@wire` service by passing values from LWC to a custom Apex method performing updates

Comment: For scenario 2 - what would be the benefit over updating with [updateRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record)?

Comment: @tsalb This was more from a learning perspective as how you can achieve this if the need be. I agree that you can use updateRecord.

Comment: That's totally fair. I'll go ahead and post up an answer of the way I currently do it when I don't use lighting data service - but just a quick disclaimer this is not preferred!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my code which I use to CRU records in LWC. Fairly basic example. I am not using String or JSON manipulation. I am also using static binding using fieldName imports

**HTML:**

```
<lightning-input label="FirstName" value={realFormData.FirstName} if:true={realFormData} onchange={updateValue}  data-field="FirstName"></lightning-input>
<lightning-input label="LastName" value={realFormData.LastName} if:true={realFormData} onchange={updateValue}  data-field="LastName"></lightning-input>

{recordId} <br/>
<button  class="slds-button" onclick={saveRecord}> Save Record</button>

<br/>
<button  class="slds-button" onclick={createRecord}> Create new hardcored CONTACT Record and load in UI</button>
```

`

**JS:**

```
import { LightningElement ,wire,track,api } from 'lwc';
import getMyContact from "@salesforce/apex/ContactController.fetchContact";
import updateMyContact from "@salesforce/apex/ContactController.updateContact";
import createMyContact from "@salesforce/apex/ContactController.createContact";
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import CONTACT_FIRSTNAME from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.FirstName';
import CONTACT_LASTNAME from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.LastName';


export default class MyCmp extends LightningElement {


 @api wiredContact;
 @api recordId;
 @api realFormData;


 @wire (getMyContact , { contactId: '$recordId' })
        fetchedContact( resp){
           this.wiredContact = resp;
           this.realFormData = {... this.wiredContact.data};

    }


    updateValue(event){



        this.realFormData = {...this.realFormData , [event.target.dataset.field] : event.detail.value};
        console.log( this.realFormData);
    }


    saveRecord(event ){

        updateMyContact({con : this.realFormData}).then(()=>{

            console.log('Refresh Apex called');
            refreshApex(this.wiredContact);
        });

    }


    createRecord(event ){
            let newContact = { [CONTACT_FIRSTNAME.fieldApiName] : 'Pikachdu' ,[CONTACT_LASTNAME.fieldApiName] : 'Raichu' };



            createMyContact({con : newContact}).then((resp)=>{
                            this.recordId = resp.Id; //this will auto call wireMethod/


            }).catch((err) => {
               // Handle any error that occurred in any of the previous
               // promises in the chain.

               console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
             });



        }




}
```

**Apex:**

```
public class ContactController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Contact fetchContact(Id contactId){
        return [SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName FROM COntact where id=:contactId LIMIT  1];
    }


    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateContact(Contact con){
        update con;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static contact createContact(Contact con){

        insert con;
        return con;


    }

}
```

Comment: +1. This looks good.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, I don't understand why "[event.target.dataset.field]" is in square brackets (indicating this is an array?) when trying to set the required field value. Can you explain?

Comment: @PhilW its to dynamically provide fieldName while creating an object. I asked similar question on SO. You can have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55589799/4121395

Answer (score 10):

In LWC, it's now preferable to attempt to use [Lightning Data Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_ui_api) first, which includes any of the [ui*Api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_ui_api) adapters such as [getRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record), [createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_create_record) and [updateRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record):

> The simplest way to work with data is to use the base Lightning components built on LDS:  lightning-record-form,  lightning-record-edit-form, or lightning-record-view-form components.
>
> If you need more customization than those components allow, use @wire to specify a Lightning Data Service wire adapter. Each wire adapter gets a different data shape.

Let's say you've exhausted your options and are looking for a scalable, repeatable way to consistently pass data between client and server. An extremely flexible datatype is then `Map<String, Object>`:

**lwcTest.html**

```html
<lightning-button label="Mutate Data" onclick={mutateData}></lightning-button>
<lightning-button label="Update Complex" onclick={updateComplexData}></lightning-button>
<lightning-button label="Update Account" onclick={updateAccountData}></lightning-button>
```

**lwcTest.js**

```js
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import wireSimpleOrComplexData  from '@salesforce/apex/DataServiceCtrl.wireSimpleOrComplexData';
import updateComplex  from '@salesforce/apex/DataServiceCtrl.updateComplex';
import updateAccount  from '@salesforce/apex/DataServiceCtrl.updateAccount';

export default class LwcTest extends LightningElement {
  @api
  get recordId() {
    return this._accountId;
  }
  set recordId(value) {
    this._accountId = value;
  }

  // private
  _accountId;
  _wiredData;
  _account;
  _contacts;
  _opportunities;

  @wire(wireSimpleOrComplexData, { accountId: '$_accountId' })
  wiredData(result) {
    this._wiredData = result; // to preserve refreshApex if needed
    if (result.data) {
      // for single sobject object spread works since this is a shallow clone
      this._account = { ...result.data.accountFromServer };

      // for collections, since every element in array is proxied, we need a deep clone
      this._contacts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data.contactsFromServer));

      // if complex objects are wanted, it might be better to do this at the result.data level
      this._opportunities = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data.opportunitiesFromServer));

      console.log(result.data.user.firstName); // UserInfo.getFirstName()
      console.log(result.data.system.now);     // System.now()
    } else {
      console.log(result.error);
    }
  }

  // Before reaching this, all the following data had their read only proxies removed
  mutateData() {
    this._account.Name += ' Updated';

    for (let contact of this._contacts) {
      contact.Email = contact.LastName + '@test.com';
    }

    for (let opp of this._opportunities) {
      opp.Name += ' Updated';
    }
  }

  updateComplexData() {
    const dataToUpdate = {
      accountAfterMutate: this._account,
      contactsAfterMutate: this._contacts,
      opportunitiesAfterMutate: this._opportunities
    }
    updateComplex({data: dataToUpdate})
      .then(result => {
        // on success, you can bind to a tracked vars to re-render them
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  updateAccountData() {
    updateAccount({accountToUpdate: this._account})
      .then(result => {
        // on success, you can bind to a tracked account variable for template view to re-render the template
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

**DataServiceCtrl.cls**

```java
  @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
  public static Map<String, Object> wireSimpleOrComplexData(String accountId) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new Map<String, Object>();
    // Data 1 single sobject
    Account acc = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id =: accountId LIMIT 1];
    result.put('accountFromServer', acc); // otherwise will be an array of 1 if directly SOQL-ed

    // Data 2 collections
    result.put('contactsFromServer', [SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =: accountId]);
    result.put('opportunitiesFromServer', [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId =: accountId]);

    // Data 3 nested properties like a POJO
    Map<String, String> userInfoMap = new Map<String, String>();
    userInfoMap.put('firstName', UserInfo.getFirstName());

    Map<String, Object> systemInfoMap = new Map<String, Object>();
    systemInfoMap.put('now', System.now());
    
    result.put('user', userInfoMap);
    result.put('system', systemInfoMap);

    return result;
  }

  @AuraEnabled
  public static Map<String, Object> updateComplex(Map<String, Object> data) {
    // Because sobjects were directly used, we can use this serialize/deserialize trick to get it back into a useable state
    Account account = (Account) JSON.deserialize(
      JSON.serialize(data.get('accountAfterMutate')),
      Account.class
    );
    List<Contact> contacts = (List<Contact>) JSON.deserialize(
      JSON.serialize(data.get('contactsAfterMutate')),
      List<Contact>.class
    );
    List<Opportunity> opportunities = (List<Opportunity>) JSON.deserialize(
      JSON.serialize(data.get('opportunitiesAfterMutate')),
      List<Opportunity>.class
    );
    // you could put database.saveResult in here if you want
    Map<String, Object> updateResults = new Map<String, Object>();
    update account;
    update contacts;
    update opportunities;
    updateResults.put('account', account);
    updateResults.put('contacts', contacts);
    updateResults.put('opportunities', opportunities);

    return updateResults;
  }

  @AuraEnabled
  public static Account updateAccount(Account accountToUpdate) {
    // no need to serialize/deserialize or transport as JSON here
    update accountToUpdate;
    return accountToUpdate;
  }
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for sharing this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I started looking around and took a cue from the topic [Migrate Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/migrate_apex), which states:

> Aura components and Lightning web components both use an Apex controller to read or **persist** Salesforce data. There are no syntax differences for the two programming models.

So based on how it worked in Lightning Aura Components, I attempted to see if it worked in LWC as well, and **Yes**, it does work.

In summary, I needed to make sure that I represent the `SObject` record/data as a JSON and then pass that as a parameter.

Below is the sample code that worked for me, where I was able to construct a JSON/manipulate an existing JSON and then pass it as a parameter to a custom Apex method to create/update a record.

**HTML**

```
<lightning-card title="My Hello World" icon-name="standard:contact">
    {recordId}
</lightning-card>
<lightning-button label="Create Record" onclick={createRecord}></lightning-button>
<lightning-button label="Update Record" onclick={udpateRecord}></lightning-button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
import createContactRecord from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.createContactRecord';
import updateContactRecord from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.updateContactRecord';
import myContact from "@salesforce/apex/ContactController.fetchContact";
....

@track recordId;
contactRecord;


// fetches a contact record from Apex
@wire (myContact)
    fetchedContact({error, data}){
        if(data){

            // this is where I save the fetched contact which will be updated later
            this.contactRecord = JSON.stringify(data);
            ...
            ...
        }
        ...
    }


// my create record JS function, where I construct a SObject and am able to 
// successfully create a record
createRecord() {

    // created a JSON representation of the Contact record, 
    // same as we would do in Lightning Aura Components

    let cont = { 'sobjectType': 'Contact' };
    cont.FirstName = 'Jayant';
    cont.LastName = 'From LWC';

    createContactRecord({newRecord: cont})
        .then(result => {
            this.recordId = result;
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.error = error;
        });
}


// my update record JS function, where I manipulate the JSON 
// and set some values to be able to successfully update the record
updateRecord() {
    let cont = JSON.parse(this.contactRecord);

    // update the fields those are required to be updated
    cont.LastName = '-LWC1';

    updateContactRecord({recordForUpdate: cont})
        .then(result => {
            this.wiredContact = result;
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.error = error;
        });
}
```

**Apex**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Contact fetchContact(){
    return [SELECT Id,Name, LastName FROM Contact where Id='xxxx' LIMIT  1];
}


@AuraEnabled
public static String createContactRecord(Contact newRecord){
    insert newRecord;
    return newRecord.Id;
}


@AuraEnabled
public static String updateContactRecord(Contact recordForUpdate){
    update recordForUpdate;
    return recordForUpdate.Name;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if getting response in string is a good idea

Comment: @PranayJaiswal This is not a real business use case but more from a learning perspective as how you can do so if you need it.

Comment: Can you have a look at my Gist? I was able to create record without passing ` { 'sobjectType': 'Contact' };` 
https://gist.github.com/pranayjswl007/c5bec83bc2ff3b0c905edd9ecb3b34ae

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Good to know this. Seems the platform deserializes it based on the parameter type as in the apex method. What is the behavior if you say add a field in your JS which does not exist in Contact? Does that give you a compile time error?

Comment: No compile time or run time error. It deserialized only the fields present on the contact. If you want string binding you can import feildName. 
https://gist.github.com/pranayjswl007/d0ef6305e8b4f0b084c48e74e5eb5a84

Comment: @JayantDas When you create the JSON contact `let cont = { 'sobjectType': 'Contact' };`, can you tell me where this is documented?  When I create a contact using `Contact con = new Contact();` and then `JSON.serialize(con);`, I see `"type":"Contact"` instead of `sobjectType`.

Comment: @DavidCheng You will need to create that *manually* using `let`. The approach is similar to as it is for [aura components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_config_action_recordid.htm)