# LWC and complex parameters

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to pass a list of objects to Apex from an LWC controller, and it looks like the Apex controller is getting the right sized list, but nothing is populated. Does anybody have any idea of what could be the problem?

Component JS code

```
refreshPeople() {
    let xxx = [];

    xxx.push({name : 'aaa', email : 'bbb'});
    xxx.push({name : '111', email : '222'});

    getPeople({peopleInfo: xxx})
        .then(result => {
            console.log('#### HERE');
            this.allPeople2 = result;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //Error Handling goes here
        });
}
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static List<EmailPerson> getPeople(List<EmailPerson> peopleInfo) {
    try {

        System.debug('####' + peopleInfo);

        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage() + ' ' + e.getStackTraceString());
    }
}

public class EmailPerson {
    @AuraEnabled
    public Id id;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String name;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String email;
    @AuraEnabled
    public Id recordTypeId;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String recordTypeName;
}
```

Note: I've tried `@wire`, the behavior is the same. The list sees the two items, but none the values on the properties are assigned

> <17:00:38:006 USER_DEBUG [20]|DEBUG|####(EmailPerson:[email=null, name=null], EmailPerson:[email=null, name=null])

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After 2 hours of struggling, and only 5 minutes after posting, here is the answer:

You have to add add `{get;set;}` **explicitly** for this to work. Changing my inner class to the below fixed the problem.

```
public class EmailPerson {
    @AuraEnabled
    public Id id {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String name {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String email {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Id recordTypeId {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String recordTypeName {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Its so weird that they expect this and just @auraEnabled is not sufficient .Will be curious for explanation from SFDC LWC Product team why do we need get and set on properties .

Comment: I’d love to hear it as well. That’s 2 hours of the clients time down the drain.

Comment: This is exactly why I avoid wrappers and use the `Map<String, Object>` datatypes.

Comment: FYI, I made an [answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/257098/718) about dealing with complex datatypes without wrappers.

Comment: I used the Map approach a lot with aura, but for things as simple as what I needed I should’ve been able to just pass an object. Making me be explicit with getter and setters is counter intuitive

Comment: Using Map<String, Object> creates too loose of a contract between the UI and backend. It opens the door for runtime bugs. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Not woking for me :(, I am using a Map<String, Object> in Apex