# Dynamically assign sObject field details in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforce-id, dynamic-binding

I have created a inline editable LWC. This solution is dynamic i.e. to add a new field on the table , i just have to add on field set  and based upon field type and access, it will be displayed in the table either in editable or read only format.

For this whole model i have created two component one is parent and one is child. In Child component i am getting object details & field details dynamically. When ever someone changes the field value in child,  i am passing them to parent using custom event :

```
const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent('changevalue', { 
                                            detail: 
                                            {
                                                fieldName : this.field.FieldAPI,
                                                value : event.target.checked,
                                                recordId : this.sobject.Id
                                            }
                                        }
                                    );  
    // Dispatches the event.
    this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
```

This part is working absolutely fine and i am getting all the details in parent but the problem is when i am trying to initiate the sObject to assign field values. In my case the field name are dynamic so i cannot use the below solution :

```
let cobj = { 'sobjectType': 'Custom Object Name' };
cobj.Name = 'Soumen';
```

I have tried the following dynamic approach but none of them working. I am only getting Id.

```
const attrdetails = event.detail;  
let moObj = {'sobjectType'  : 'Master_Order__c',  'Id' : attrdetails.recordId, [attrdetails.fieldName] : attrdetails.value};
```

or `let moobj = {};
    moobj[attrdetails.fieldName] = attrdetails.value;
    moobj.Id = attrdetails.recordId`

JSON output of moObj :

```
{"sobjectType":"Master_Order__c","Id":"a0T22000000R7RNEA0"}
```

Pardon me for any spelling mistake.

Thanks,
Soumen

Comment: Try this : `moobj["'" + attrdetails.fieldName + "'"] = attrdetails.value;`

Comment: Why have you put square brackets around the attribute name? That makes no sense in JSON or with JavaScript objects. 
[attrdetails.fieldName] : attrdetails.value should not have the square brackets...

Comment: I have tried this :  moobj["'" + attrdetails.fieldName + "'"] = attrdetails.value. It is also not working.  @PhilW : I was referring this link => https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257058/how-do-i-pass-a-sobject-record-from-lwc-to-a-custom-apex-method-to-persist-data. Here they are using this.realFormData = {...this.realFormData , [event.target.dataset.field] : event.detail.value};

Comment: Try it just as moobj[attrdetails.fieldName] = attrdetails.value

Comment: Thanks Phil that worked. I have tried that earlier but  i was doing a silly mistake by catching picklist value  using event.target.checked instead of event.detail.value